# SMS is not sending to multiple mobile numbers

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

In my codeigniter project sms has been integrated. Sms is working fine. I have to upload a text file, which will contain mobile numbers and need to send sms to that mobile numbers. I get the mobile numbers from the uploaded file, but message does not send. Here is my Controller code:

```
public function sendBulkSms() {
    $config['upload_path'] = 'bulk_sms/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('text_file')) {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    //------------------send sms---------------
        $file_content = file_get_contents(base_url()."bulk_sms/".$upload_data['file_name']);
        $mobileNO = explode(',', $file_content);
      //$mobileNO = array("8801670750680", "8801942762160");
        $smsFormat = "Hi, this is a test message";

        function httpGet($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $output;
        }

        $user = "SomeUser";
        $pass = "SomePass";
        $sid = "8804445650490";
        $url = "my_sms_api_url";
        $SMSText = urlencode($smsFormat);

        foreach($mobileNO as $mobile_no){
            echo httpGet("my_sms_api_url?user=$user&password=$pass&sender=$sid&SMSText=$SMSText&GSM=$mobile_no&type=longSMS&datacoding=1");
        }
     // -----------end send sms----------            
    }
}
```

From the browser, if I upload a text file with the following mobile number:

014151515, 012181818, 013484848

it shows
-13014151515 -13012181818 -13013484848

here -13 added to the numbers

if I use

> $mobileNO = array("016151515", "017181818");

insted of

> $mobileNO = explode(',', $file_content);

then it works
I can't understand from where the extra digits (-13) added. Please help me to find out.

Comment: Strip the spaces between the numbers and keep them separated only by comma: 014151515,012181818,013484848 then try an see if the -13 is gone.

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($file_content)`? Also, can you `echo` the string you pass to `httpGet`?

Comment: @Alex Tartan 

output of var_dump($file_content) is 
string(29) "014151515,012181818,013484848" 
this is as I expect.

I echo the $mobile_no variable which I passed to httpGet and the output is
014151515012181818013484848

Comment: `-13014151515 -13012181818 -13013484848` when you get this, where you put `var_dump()` ? or it's from Admin server of SMS console ?

Comment: @tarikul05 when function httpGet($url) calls it returns $output variable. and [-13014151515 -13012181818 -13013484848] is the output of $output variable.

Comment: @Mustafa may be your Admin(sms) panel have logic to CONCAT `-13`. please check there